# How to add ObjectNodes with same names?

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to create xml output for web endpoint.
Building xml with ObjectNodes - and i fail to add node with the same name,
So i need

```
  <feature_set>
       <feature>
         ...
       </feature>
       <feature>
        ...
       </feature>
....
```

I am trying to do like this, and it won't work:

```
ObjectNode featureSetNode = ((ObjectNode) sequenceNode).putObject("feature_set");
        
        for (SimpleFeature feature : simpleFeatures ) {
            JsonNode featureNode = featureSetNode.putObject("feature");
        }
```

I am getting only one `feature` node as a result.
How can i add nodes with the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let jackson automatically convert the object using annotations like this:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "feature_set")
public class FeatureRoot {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false) //this removes wrapper tag
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="feature")
    private List<Feature> features;

    public FeatureRoot(List<Feature> features) {
        this.features = features;
    }

    public List<Feature> getFeatures() {
        return features;
    }

}
public class Feature {
    private String name;

    public Feature(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

The following code

```
    FeatureRoot featureRoot = new FeatureRoot(
        List.of(
            new Feature("test"),
            new Feature("asd")
        )
    );
    XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
    String xml = mapper.writeValueAsString(featureRoot);
```

will produce

```
<feature_set>
    <feature>
        <name>test</name>
    </feature>
    <feature>
        <name>asd</name>
    </feature>
</feature_set>
```

Comment: I need exact format to be sent to client, similar keys, not array. 
XML does allow that. And even JSON format apart from java-jackson, doesn't restric that, it's recommended not to use, but not resctricted. 
May be Jackson is wrong choise, what is the proper way than?

Comment: It may be syntactically valid but it's useless. In javascript `JSON.parse('{"a": 1, "a": 6}')` produces an object `{a: 6}`. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159 says the keys should (not must) be unique.

Comment: @Cyryl i totally understand and agree with you, but we have old legacy client application that happily parse xml with same key names, doing it for ages, and out of my power to change it. So i am making server that must send exact xml object

Comment: @Mira right, I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. Let me check...

Comment: I didn't got notification about answer changed, so read it after found out other way. Anyway thaks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To create same-keys entries from scratch use this:

```
        ObjectNode featureSetNode = sequenceNode.putObject("feature_set");
        ArrayNode featureNode = featureSetNode.putArray("feature");

        for (SimpleFeature feature : simpleFeatures ) {
            ObjectNode featureNodeImpl = featureNode.addObject();
            featureNodeImpl.put("start", feature.getSeqRegionStart());
        }

       XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
       String xml = mapper.writeValueAsString(featureRoot);
```